# Yet Another Improperly Migrated Question

Tags: discussion

To wit:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82306/images-appear-broken-due-to-timthumb-resizing

I know that WPSE mods discuss migrations with other sites' mods before migrating questions to them. Do we not get the same courtesy?

It seems that a ton of obviously WordPress-specific questions *don't* get migrated here, yet these obviously-outside-WPSE-scope questions *do* get migrated here. It is frustrating, because then we have to community-moderate the question, and the asker gets (rightfully) frustrated.

Comment: I know what you mean about [improperly migrated Questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82373/latex-packages-in-wordpress). The Answer to that Q was very simple: "Nope, can't do in WP (.com), make a feature request with them."

Answer (score 2):

We do not discuss migrations usually, because of the new way migrations work now: The moment we close the migrated question as *off topic* here, the migration is *rejected,* and the question goes back to the original site.

During the last 90 days 74 questions have been migrated to our site from 5 other sites. We rejected 13. That’s not enough data to state a pattern. We get ~60 questions per day on our site … I don’t think those 74 additional questions are a problem.

The inappropriate migrations make 0.4% of all questions. We are six moderators plus 38 users who can cast close votes. We can handle that.

Comment: That's roughly a 20% rejection rate, which IMHO is high enough to cause concern. But more concerning is the number of obviously in-scope questions that just get answered at SO, or WebApps, or wherever, *on top of* having to deal with 20% of questions migrated here being *off-topic*. If all of the actually *on-topic* questions from SO got migrated here, that 20% off-topic would be 10%, or even 5%, and I wouldn't be as bothered by those off-topic questions that get migrated here.

Comment: We cannot do anything to get SO questions to our site. We talked with the SO mods about that – without result. As long as the community on the site the question has been asked think it is on topic there it will stay there.

Comment: Yeah, I do get that - but that just makes *this* sort of thing that much more frustrating. And if the SE powers-that-be are willing to leave the situation as-is, then so be it. I don't understand why SE would implement a *WordPress*-specific network site, and *not* instruct mods on other sites to direct *100-percent WordPress-specific* questions to that site, but again: so be it.

Comment: "*The inappropriate migrations make 0.4% of all questions.*" - not really the point, is it? 13 out of 74 *migrated* questions is **18%**. The real issue is that SO *hoards WordPress questions* while they and others send us *off-topic, TimThumb/CSS/etc.* (i.e. *hot-potato*) questions.

Comment: Many questions may belong to more than one site, and then they [should stay where they are](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). I don’t like the current WP situation too, but as long as even our experienced members continue to answer WP questions on SO it will not change.

Comment: Interesting link. It includes this line: "*Our audience is large enough to allow a considerable amount of specialization: Apple, Ubuntu, WordPress and Database Administrators **all cover topics that previously belonged on** Super User, Stack Overflow or Server Fault.*" That **previously belonged** implies that such topics **no longer belong** on SO, but rather on the *more-specialized* site. It seems that there is no real interest in *enforcing* that, unfortunately.

Comment: Close voted as off topic - this should be migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com as it is clearly an issue for the mods there.

Comment: Actually, the question, er, in question was migrated here from WebApps, not SO.

Comment: @anu, per [FAQ], "This site is for meta discussion about wordpress.stackexchange.com. Any question relevant to our community is welcome here." While it *could* be relevant to meta.SO or any other meta, it being relevant *here* makes it clearly on-topic.